# when creating certificate i got java.io.filenotfoundexception:myapplication.keystore <access is denied> in android

Tags: android, keystore

Hi I am creating the certificate keystore for my android application to submit to android market.but i get the access is denied.

I am getting the following error :

keytool error:java.io.filenotfoundexception:myapplication.keystore

```
  at java.io.fileoutputstream.open<native method>
  at java.io.fileoutputstream.<init><unknown source>
  at java.io.fileoutputstream.<init><unknown source>
  at sun.security.tools.keytool.docommands<unknown source>
  at sun.security.tools.keytool.run<unknown source>
  at sun.security.tools.keytool.main<unknown source>
```

please help me and provide the sample step to create the certificate for my application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem by log in as administrator to the command prompt and solved the problem. By this type of action of creating the certificate we have to run the command prompt as the administrator and give the necessary camand to create the certificate.

Comment: @hrushikesh Great answer.. Just now i stuck with this problem. You helped to recover me